# How to create indexes from two django apps in Haystack?

Tags: django, django-haystack

My haystack search in working on one django app. But how to implement same on two different apps.

what i have tried.Created different search_index.py in both apps.
App1

```
import datetime
from haystack import indexes
from app1.models import App1

 class app1Index(indexes.SearchIndex, indexes.Indexable):
    text = indexes.EdgeNgramField(document=True, use_template=True)
    app1_text = indexes.CharField(model_attr='app1_text',null=True)
    tags = indexes.CharField(model_attr='tags')

    def get_model(self):
        return App1
```

App2

```
import datetime
from haystack import indexes
from app2.models import App2

class app2Index(indexes.SearchIndex, indexes.Indexable):
    text = indexes.EdgeNgramField(document=True, use_template=True)
    app2_title = indexes.CharField(model_attr='app2_title',null=True)

    def get_model(self):
        return App2
```

This is search.html

```
        {% for result in page.object_list %}
        <p>
                <a href="{{ result.object.get_absolute_url }}">{{ result.object.wish_text }}</a>
                <a href="{{ result.object.get_absolute_url }}">{{ result.object.title }}</a>

        </p>
```

I have data template for both apps in correct place.
App1 
    {{ object.app1_text }}
App2 
    {{ object.app2_title }}

If i dont use App2 search_index then for App1 it is working fine.
Also rebuild_index and update_index work for both apps .

Question : How Can i make it work for both apps ?

Comment: I don't understand what isn't working. Can you clarify your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I deleted everything everything and added again.

```
1 search_indexes.py in first app
1 search_indexes.py in second app
and a search.html template that fetch the results for both.
```

and Bingo this time worked perfect. So what was the issue . :) me too dont know may be some typo error.

```
If somebody need explaination on answer please drop a comment here :)
```

I am able to search on multiple apps now.

Any other solution is welcomed .

Accepted for future reference.

Answer (score 0):

Well also i do not fully understand the problem you want to point at
So as far as i understood, building the index does work, which means app(1|2)Index do find the proper template.
It might be an url issue of app2. For further investigation the template might be of interest